# What does the whole letter in Black Panther by Prince NJobu say?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

In the scene where Killmonger goes to the Ancestral Plane and is back at his apartment when he was a kid, he finds a letter written by his dad, Prince N'Jobu.

I paused my DVD to try to read the letter but because of the angle and focus of the camera for the movie, I can only read parts of it and not the whole thing.  It seems like the parts I can read basically says his thoughts to helping oppressed people of African descent.

Does anyone have a link to a script or something that lists the whole letter?  I'm just curious to read the letter as a whole.

Comment: Keep in mind this is a movie prop; the audience is expected to get *that it is* a letter, but not expected to pause and read it. As such, its content **will not** be carefully crafted by writers/showrunners.  It's probably written by someone in the prop department, *who may not know the full arc of the story for security reasons*. So expect [Randy Newman Star Wars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SK-p3mtyhRc) quality...

Comment: @Harper Your point is valid for some productions, but in the modern age of cinema, creators are aware of obsessive fans, DVDs, and 4K streaming services. Big budget productions like MCU films *are* going to sweat the details on props that will only be visible for a second on screen, and they have the resources to patch secrets into close-ups in post-production if necessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [cinemablend](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2460241/someone-transcribed-njobus-journal-from-black-panther-and-its-heartbreaking):

> YouTube user Aznmarty256 (via [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/9r7qoc/transcription_of_njobus_journal/)) took the time to pause when Killmonger is sifting through N'Jobu's journal and transcribe exactly what he wrote to his son. Take a look:
>
> > Ungubani? Who are you? I asked this question of myself many times. Often times, I do not know. But I do know I am no longer the man my country knew.
> >
> > Maybe love? My son?
> >
> > It has all changed me. T'Chaka must see what we can do, how we can change the course of time for the people who struggle so much in this land. Strangers to me, but my brothers and sisters still. How can I look at them, with the same skin as me, stolen from the same place I came from and not reach out to them? How can I sit idly by and watch in pain and return to Wakanda as if there was nothing to see at all?
> >
> > Who am I? A war dog who will not leave the lost tribe behind again. Who are you, my son? You will ask this one day and know the answer:
> >
> > N'Jadaka, son of N'Jobu.

I also tried to take the screenshot of it:

[image]